How Does One Show That A R.V Has CDF F?
I'm self studying probability using Statistics 101 book.
In chapter 3 there's a question(ex. 9):

Let F1 and F2 be CDFs, 0 <p< 1, and F(x) = pF1(x) + (1 − p)F2(x) for
all x.
(a) Show directly that F has the properties of a valid CDF (see
Theorem 3.6.3). The distribution defined by F is called a mixture of
the distributions defined by F1 and F2.
(b) Consider creating an r.v. in the following way. Flip a coin with
probability p of Heads. If the coin lands Heads, generate an r.v.
according to F1; if the coin lands Tails, generate an r.v. according
to F2. Show that the r.v. obtained in this way has CDF F.

Part a is easy and I was able to show it.
I'm having a bit trouble with part b - I understand why a r.v created that way has the CDF F(x) but how can I show it in a mathematically correct way?
I tried showing it by:
Let $ P(X \leq x) = F_1(x) $ and $ P(Y \leq y) = F_2(y) $ for all $ x $ and $ y $.
Let $ P(Z = z) = \text{Bern}(p) $.
Define $ g(X, Y, Z) = \begin{cases} 
X & \text{if } Z = 1 \\
Y & \text{if } Z = 0 
\end{cases} $.
Let $ T = g(X, Y, Z) $.
Then, to construct $ P(T \leq t) $:
$$
P(T \leq t) = P(g(X, Y, Z) \leq t) 
$$
Since $ T = X $ when $ Z = 1 $ and $ T = Y $ when $ Z = 0 $, we have:
$$
P(T \leq t) = P(X \leq t \mid Z = 1)P(Z = 1) + P(Y \leq t \mid Z = 0)P(Z = 0)
$$
Given that $ Z $ (the coin flip) is implicitly independent of $ X $ and $ Y $, this simplifies to:
$$
P(T \leq t) = F_1(t) \cdot p + F_2(t) \cdot (1 - p) = F(t)
$$
where $ F(t) $ is the combined cumulative distribution function of $ T $.
But I'm not sure if that way is correct or if there's a better way.
Thanks in advance.
